# How to enable ClearType fonts when using TeamViewer?

Tags: windows-7, teamviewer

When I remote to my friend computer, the fonts on his screen are very ugly, ClearType fonts are turned off. I tried to use best quality for the display setting but it doesn't work.

How can I enable it when remoting by TeamViewer? I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After TeamViewer session is starter hit Windows key, enter "cleartype" in Start menu search and choose "Customize ClearType text" then "Turn on ClearType".

You can also visit this site in Internet Explorer: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/tune.aspx
It works on older versions of Windows.

Now, ClearType is working :)

Comment: You are the man!!! I'm so dummy not to treat it as the native mornitor ^^